# How to Display the text in a textarea in another part of the html code or in another textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to write something in a `<textarea>`, and then click a button and have the text I wrote in the textarea displayed in another textarea or inside a `<div>`.

I'm not sure what code I should try. I'm very new to coding. I tried the following which clearly did not work.

My JS:

```
<script>
function myFunction(){
   var input = document.getElementbyId('input').innerHTML;
   document.getElementbyId('output').innerHTML;
}
</script>
```

My HTML:

```
<textarea id='input'></textarea>
<textarea id='output'></textarea>
<button onclick= 'myFunction()'>Click</button>
```

Comment: You don't correctly close out `myFunction`'s definition with a closing curly brace. Do you see errors in your web console?  You should.  And those errors will tell you where your issues are.  You also don't assign the value of your `input` element to the value of your `output` element.

Comment: I want to apologise for such a mistake. I'm very very new to coding. I did not know how I could use values. @Marc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had an error calling `getElementbyId`. And you can use `value` to assign a text value. Also, you haven't closed your function.

```js
function myFunction(){
   var input = document.getElementById('input');
   var output = document.getElementById('output');
   
   output.value = input.value;   
}
```

```html
<textarea id='input'></textarea>
<textarea id='output'></textarea>
<button onclick='myFunction()'>Click</button>
```

Comment: Glad to help :)